# Add Firestore document to observable

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have an observable `user` and I want to add a Firestore document to it. Right now I'm getting an error in my IDE: "Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'Observable'." How would I do this? I also want to listen for changes.

```
//The observable
user: Observable<User>;

//Fetching the user, then trying to assign it to the variable
this.afs.doc(`Users/${uid}`).ref.get().then((doc)=> {
    this.user = doc.data();
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`angularfire2`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) you could listen for Firestore changes with [`.valueChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges)

```
user$: Observable<User> = this.afs.doc(`Users/${uid}`).valueChanges();

userSubscription: Subscription = this.user$
  .subscribe((data) => {
     console.log('user$ observable data: ', data);
  });
```

If you want to include metadata, such as the document id, you could use [`.snapshotChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges) and get the data using a few `map`s.

If you are using RxJS 6 it may look something like:

```
user$: Observable<User> = this.afs.doc(`Users/${uid}`)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
     map(changes => {
        changes.map(change => {
           return change.payload.doc.data();
        })
     })
  );

userSubscription: Subscription = this.user$
  .subscribe((data) => {
     console.log('user$ observable data with metadata: ', data);
  });
```

Or the same `.snapshotChanges()` functionality, but shorter:

```
user$: Observable<User> = this.afs.doc(`Users/${uid}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
     map(changes => changes.map(change => change.payload.doc.data() )) );

userSubscription: Subscription = this.user$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: i've been trying to write this for 2 hours, thanks!